# Printing the value of a 0-initialized array element prints nothing, why?

Tags: c, char, printf, format-specifiers

I have to initialize a char array to 0's. I did it like

```
char array[256] = {0};
```

I wanted to check if it worked so I tried testing it

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char s[256] = {0};
    printf("%c\n", s[10]);
    return 0;
}
```

After I compile and run it, the command line output shows nothing.

What am I missing ? Perhaps I initialized the array in a wrong manner ?

Comment: What do you expect it to print?

Comment: It prints a literal zero and so `printf` believes it's done because that marks the end of a string.

Comment: my bad, get it wrong :) @SouravGhosh

Comment: @RatulSharker not a problem. :)

Comment: a 0 is an integer  a '0' is a character.  so this line: `char s[256] = {0};` fills the array with `'\0'`  (0x00) when you want it to fill the array with `0x30`  Suggest using: `char s[256] = {'0'};`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR --** `%c` is the character representation. Use `%d` to see the decimal `0` value.

Related , from `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1, (*emphasis mine*)

> `c`          If no `l` length modifier is present, the `int` argument is converted to an
>   `unsigned char`, **and the resulting character is written.**

FYI, see the list of [printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) values.

That said, for a hosted environment, `int main()` should be `int main(void)`, at least to conform to the standard.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed had to change from `%c` to `%d`

Answer (score 5):

You are printing `s[10]` as a character (`%c`), and the numeric value of `s[10]` is `0`, which represents the character `\0`, which means end of string and has no textual representation. For this reason you are not seeing anything.

If you want to see the numeric value instead of the character value, use `%d` to print it as a decimal (integer) number:

```
printf("%d\n", s[10]);
```

Note that end of string isn't the same as end of line, as said in one of your comments. End of string means that any string operation over a character sequence must stop when the first `\0` arrives. If the character sequence has anything else after `\0`, it won't be printed, because the string operation stops on the first `\0` character.

An end of line is, however, a normal character, which visual effect is to say the terminal or text editor to print the next character after the end of line in a new line.

If you want to have a vector full of end of line characters (and print them as such), you have to travel the vector and fill it:

```
char s[256];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
     s[i] = '\n';

printf("%c\n", s[10]);
```

The ASCII (decimal/numerical) value of the end of line character (`\n`) is 12, so, the following snippet will be equivalent:

```
char s[256];
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
     s[i] = 12;

printf("%c\n", s[10]);
```

That doesn't work however (it doesn't print a new line):

```
char s[256] = {'\n'}; // or {12};

printf("%c\n", s[10]);
```

because the effect of `{'\n'}` is to assign `\n` to the first element of the array, and the remainings 255 character are filled with value 0, no matter which type of array are you making (`char[]`, `int[]` or whatever). If you write an empty pair of brackets `{}`, all the elements will be 0.

So, these two statements are equivalent:

```
char s[256] = {}; // Implicit filling to 0.
char s[256] = {0}; // Implicit filling to 0 from the second element.
```

However, without defining the array:

```
char s[256];
```

The array is not filling (not initialized), so, each element of `s` will have anything, until you fill it with values, for example, with a `for`.

I hope with all of this examples you get the whole picture.

Comment: Thank you! I was printing a newline so it drove me crazy... couldn't tell why nothing is being printed while I expected 0

Comment: @TonyTannous Edited.